# Use WP_Query for custom post type but result get empty

Tags: plugins, php

When I am using this code on my plugin page, I'm getting empty array but not the required result.

What's wrong with this code?

```
$defaults_arr = array(
'post_type' => 'at-subscription',
'suppress_filters' => true,
'order' => 'ASC',);
//
$query_r    = wp_parse_args($args,$defaults_arr);
$get_posts  = new WP_Query();

print_r($get_posts->query($query_r));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10, // -1 to fetch all posts
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'at-subscription', // the post type 
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 

// For displaying all posts related to at-subscription
print_r( $posts_array );
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: sorry bro its also given empty array

Comment: i am developing plugin and in my registration form call by short code on registration form this post not coming with use of WP_Query() or any other wordpress functions